# How to send FILE (any extension) to phone via sms?

Tags: android, ios, iphone, blackberry, windows-phone

Would anyone be so kind to please explain me how do I sent file, regardless of its extension (e.g. doc, docx, pdf,...) to someone's cell phone, regardless of cell phone's model/company/production year/specifications? Either via sms, mms, or whatever. I found online wide range of sms text message sending applications. Some are free, some not. Majority of them don't work and sms never arrives but few of them work. However noone of the working ones offer file sending. I would prefer but not require desktop application instead of website. Could you please tell me how to send particular file to the cell phone? Note that it is completely irrelevant what kind of cell phone it is as I am looking for complete/general solution for all cell phones. **Very important:** I am looking to send from either desktop or laptop computer with Windows 10 installed.

Comment: You cant send a file just like that. Forget SMS

Comment: what should I use then? Instructions similar to those https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-send-a-file-via-sms-to-a-cell-phone  don't work